# get the return value from a C executable, called from a Visual Studio 2010 form

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to execute a C exe compiled used gcc from a form created in VB 2010. The C executable has an int main function int main(argv[],argc)

I have been able to pass arguments to the function using:

```
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "trial4.exe"
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True


    If SelectedFileNames_Path > "" Then

        filename_strings = Chr(34) + SelectedFileNames_Path + Chr(34)

        If LocalTimeSelectBtn.Checked = True Then
            SelectedTime = LocalTime
        ElseIf GMTTimeSelectBtn.Checked = True Then
            SelectedTime = GMTTime
        End If

        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = SelectedTime + " " + filename_strings + " "

        AddHandler myProcess.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf NetOutputDataHandler

        SelectedFolder.Items.Clear()
        myProcess.Start()
        myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine()
        myProcess.Close()

    Else
        MsgBox(" Please select a directory before generating the CSV files ")
    End If
```

When Trial4.exe is executed with arguments, there is a return type (int) that tells if the program ran successfully.

I am not able to find any way through which I could get the return value from the C executable in this VB form.  I am using Visual Studio 2010.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,